# Monte Carlo Gaussian function

Tags: python, function, loops

For a class assignment I need to do the following (sorry for the badly formatted picture):

[image]

So far I have:

```
import math

def gaussian(x):
    return ((1 / math.sqrt(2 * math.pi) * math.e) ** ( (-x ** 2) / 2))

# Problem 2.

def under_curve(x, y):
    if 0 <= y <= gaussian(x):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Problem 3.

def greater_than(x, a):
    if x > a:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Problem 4.

def less_than(x, b):
    if x < b:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Problem 5.

def monte_carlo_gaussian(a, b, n):
    import numpy as np
    x = np.random.uniform(low=a, high=b, size=n)
    y = np.random.uniform(low=a, high=b, size=n)
    
    i = 0 
    ndartsunder = 0
    ndarts = 0 
    for xi in x:
        yi = y[i]
        
        if less_than(x, b) is True:
            ndartsunder = ndartsunder + 1 * under_curve(xi, yi)
            ndarts += 1
        i += 1
    prob_under_curve = ndartsunder / ndarts
    return b * prob_under_curve
```

The problem I am having is with monte_carlo_gaussian.
I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\agsmi\Desktop\st114\homework7.py", line 104, in <module>
    print(monte_carlo_gaussian(-1.644854, 1.644854, 10))

  File "C:\Users\agsmi\Desktop\st114\homework7.py", line 92, in monte_carlo_gaussian
    if less_than(x, b) is True:

  File "C:\Users\agsmi\Desktop\st114\homework7.py", line 74, in less_than
    if x < b:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

But I am just very confused with how to design this function overall. Any help or tips to get me going in the right direction would be appreciated. I think I need to implement the gaussian function too but I am not sure how/where. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't `if less_than(x, b)` be `if less_than(xi, b)`? `x` is an iterable, so it doesn't make sense to compare a list of numbers to one number (unless you're trying to compare to the max and min values in the list). It especially doesn't make sense to do the exact same comparison over and over again in a loop; neither `x` nor `b` are changing in each loop iteration.

Comment: @RandomDavis you are right I should have used xi

Comment: That's good. Also, FYI, if you still run into trouble, then it's fine to post a new question about the specific trouble you're having. Some people ask follow-up questions on their own post, which have nothing to do with the initial question, which is why I bring that up.

Comment: @RandomDavis thank you!